# CSS media query for iPhone XR doesn't work?

Tags: css, iphone, phonegap

I'm working on a hybrid mobile app using Phonegap.

And everything works fine apart from one issue which only exist on the `iPhone XR`.

The issue doesn't exist on iPhone X or iPhone XS etc.

Basically, my CSS media query doesn't work on (it doesn't do anything) on iPhone XR.

This is what i am using for **iPhone XR**:

```
/* iPhone XR */
@media only screen 
    and (min-device-width: 414px) 
    and (min-device-height: 896px) 
    and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
    and (orientation: portrait) { 
    /* my styles goes here */



}
```

Is there something that I am missing and why is this media query doesn't do anything on on iphone xr?

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

The following CSS media query works fine on iphone x and iphone xs max:

```
    /* iphone x */
@media only screen 
    and (device-width : 375px) 
    and (device-height : 812px) 
    and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 3) {


}
```

Comment: There is a difference between screen pixels and rendered pixels. I mean a phone with a resolution of 1920x1080 may render a website at 910x540 pixels. Also `-webkit` is a browser specific prefix so it might not work for firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/-webkit-device-pixel-ratio

Comment: @SuperDJ, not entirely sure what you are referring to but I have edited my question in case something wasn't clear.

Answer (score 3):

According to the iPhone XR screen size:

[image]

The correct media query for iPhone XR is:

```
@media only screen 
and (device-width : 375px) 
and (device-height : 812px) 
and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
@media only screen and (device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {}
```